# creating a box side by side using JavaScript and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create two separate boxes side by side which shows like the image given below. My JavaScript code is written below. The issue is when I am trying to create the second box it comes down, whereas I want the box beside the first box.

```js
//define your javascript libraries
resource = [
  "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js",
  "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/justgage/1.0.1/justgage.min.js"
]

//add scripts to head
$.getScript(resource[0], function() {
  $.getScript(resource[1], init)
})

//start your widget
init = function() {
  var g = new JustGage({
    id: "gauge",
    value: parseInt($("#6becbadfe55c4b04a589afae48ea4843").text()),
    min: -1000,
    max: 1000,
    title: "Net Income margin %"
  });

  //refresh gauge when calcvalue changes
  $(calcValue).on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    g.refresh($(this).text())
  })
}
```

```html
<DIV id=gauge style="HEIGHT: 325px; WIDTH: 570px"></DIV>
<SPAN id=calcValue><SpotfireControl id="6becbadfe55c4b04a589afae48ea4843" /></SPAN>
```

Now the output which I am seeking for is look like:

[image]

Need help how to do this?

Comment: Where is the code to create box?

Comment: <DIV id=gauge style="HEIGHT: 325px; WIDTH: 570px"></DIV>

Comment: CSS is managing the aspect/position of your objects, not Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

A div Element has a `display: block` by default.

Blocks are not on the same line by default.

You have to make your box inline. For instance `display: inline-block;`

Comment: How to modify??It didn't work

Comment: <div style="display: inline-block; height: 325px; width: 570px"></div>

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the div's css to `display:inline block` or just change it to an inline element like a `<span>`

You could also look at float:left

The other option would be css3 fanciness involving grid or flexbox but I suspect that would be overkill

Comment: Could you please show me??I am new in this platform

Answer (score 0):

CSS is made for managing style/position, not Javascript.

html

```
<div id="gauge"></div>
<span id="calcValue"><!-- ... --></span>
```

css

```
#gauge, #calcValue {
    display: inline-block;
}

#gauge {
    width: 570px;
    height: 325px;
}

#calcValue {
    width: calc(100% - 570px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="somthing">dsfdsf</div>
<div class="somthing">dsfdsf</div>
<div class="somthing">sdfdsfsdf</div>
```

### CSS

```
.somthing{
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```